# Initializing python Defaultdict

Tags: python, python-3.x, defaultdict

Is there a way to initialize a dict the following way:

```
component_map = {}
component_map[component] = {'in': [], 'out': [], 'degree': 0}
```

For example, I can create a `defaultdict` that will give me a `[]` by default, like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
component_map = defaultdict(list)
component_map['component']
# []
```

How would I initialize it so that calling `component_map['component']` returns `{'in': [], 'out': [], 'degree': 0}` ?

Comment: With a function returning that.

Comment: @HeapOverflow great, would you want to show an example of that in an answer then?

Comment: The only requirement is that the argument to `defaultdict` be a callable that doesn't require an argument. The type `list` is a callable that, when called with no arguments, returns an empty list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
component_map = defaultdict(lambda: {'in': [], 'out': [], 'degree': 0})
```